# "Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource" error while trying to host Python + Flask server on Render

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to host a Python + Flask server on Render and I am getting the next error:

Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

```
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('stopwords')
```

I have already imported nltk and downloaded stopwords:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Any help will be much appreciated :(